# django.utils.dataStructures.MultiValueDictKeyError 'name' - while receiving data from post request send by pure JavaScript using fetch API

Tags: javascript, django

What is the correct way of receiving data from post request in django.The request comes from pure javaScript using the fetch api. below is my code snippets:

```
def change_group_name(request, pk):

     if request.method == 'POST':       
     user = request.user
     name = request.POST.get('name', False)
     pk = request.POST.get('id', False)

     print('==========================================')
     print(name)
     print('============================================')
```

I get an error when i try to print the `name` 
`django.utils.dataStructures.MultiValueDictKeyError 'name'`

`javascript`

```
    async sendInfo(name ,id , csrf_token) {

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/group/detail/10/settings/change',{
        method: 'post',
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken':csrf_token
        },
        body: {'id': JSON.stringify(id), 'name': JSON.stringify(name)}
    })
}
```

below is the `urlpattern` :
    `urlpatterns = [
         url(r'^group/detail/(?P<pk>\d+)/settings/change$',change_group_name, 
         name='group_settings_change'),
     ]`

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the root problem but try to change your request body to `body: JSON.stringify({id: id, name: name})`

Comment: i tried that but still can't get it done . I have also updated my question and included  the urlpattern for my `view`